# change variable class, without dropping labels

Tags: r, data.table, label, tidyverse

I have a df that looks something like this

```
library(Hmisc)
library(data.table)
df–<- structure(list(id1 = structure(c(108791, 154542, 32742, 51033, 123998, 165156, 159221, 51806, 82668, 94864), label = "label 1", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
                      id2 = structure(c(372925, 14792, 24970, 24970, 24970, 24970, 324930, 14792, 14792, 23284), label = "label 2", format.stata = "%12.0g")), 
                 row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
contents(tst)
#      Labels Storage
# id1 label 1  double
# id2 label 2  double
```

I consist, of multiple variables that are labelled.
I am going through some data management using `data.table`. My issue is that every time I do some manipulations, my variables lose their labels.

Take the following example:
I would like to change the variable class, from numeric to character using the following approach:

```
idvars <- c("id1","id2")
df_final <- setDT(df)[,(idvars):=lapply(.SD,function(x) as.character(x)),.SDcols=idvars]
```

While df_final correctly changes variable class, the resulting variables are no longer labelled.

```
contents(df_final)
#      Storage
# id1 character
# id2 character
```

Does anyone know how I can continue to use data table to do data management while keeping the variables labels?

thanks

Comment: what is the use of `Hmisc` library in this example?

Comment: To use the `contents` function. It shows that while `df ` has the labels, `df_final` does not